# cakephp - triggered - after execution of query

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

How can change output one of model in all queries?

This means that queries run on this model, then go to a specific function.

for example, in user model, how remove password field for all queries

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the following to your model:

```
public function afterFind($results, $primary = false){
    foreach ($results as $key => $val) {
        unset($results[$key][$this->alias]['password']);
    }

    return $results;
}
```

This should also work:

```
public function afterFind($results, $primary = false){
    return Hash::remove($results, '{n}.'.$this->alias.'.password');
}
```

Comment: there's no way that there will be exceptional cases?

Comment: Not any more. It used to be the case that `$results` could be structured differently when `find()` would be called on the primary model vs recursively in an associated one. [This behavior was fixed in 2.6.0](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/4223). Make sure you are on CakePHP 2.6 or higher.